# How to generate semantic table markup using Marionette CollectionView and LayoutView

Tags: javascript, marionette

I'm trying to use Marionettes `CollectionView` and `LayoutView` to achieve what can be done with the `CompositeView`. The problem I'm having right now is that my `LayoutView` uses `tbody` to hook into, when the `CollectionView` gets called a div is produced which is standard so my output tr tags have a structure `tbody > div > tr` which is semantically incorrect. My problem is that I'm not sure how to correct this though, I need the `tbody` there to hook into and setting any other tagName on the CollectionView will still make things incorrect?

**JS**

```
var Row = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: '#row',
    tagName: 'tr'
});

// Create a TableRowView -> ItemView
var Rows = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    childView: Row
});

var Table = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: '#table',
    regions: {
        'tbody': '.js-tbody'
    }
});
```

**Link to code:** http://jsfiddle.net/gqmcy2yn/5/

Comment: Why not use CompositeView? You can make whole table as view and put rows in specific place.

Comment: I have been reading that the CompositeView will eventually be deprecated and that the new approach to achieving this goal would be by using CollectionView and LayoutView so I wanted to try that out here

Comment: As I understand they will allow `template` and `childViewContainer` to use in CollectionView so it will work the same way as CompositeView. It is totally ok to use CompositeViews for now.

Comment: Ahh, sorry I'm very new to using Marionette and didn't know that these settings would be ported over!

Comment: Just reading this though - My long-term vision is that we have two types of views: View and CollectionView. The CollectionView would be unchanged, but the View would effectively just be a LayoutView, allowing you to nest child views indefinitely.

Comment: You are correct. CollectionView inherit everything from View and will have template and regions also.

Comment: Also, Mn3 has a new option to `replaceEl` on regions, which fixes the dreaded 'extra div' problem. So you can set a layoutview with a table template, setting the `thead` and `tbody` as regions, then when showing, replaceEl, so everything is semantically correct